# PHP scripting with cookies

Tags: php, html, cookies, web

In order to use multiple style sheets in my website each having a different function I need to use php scripting with cookies. The script reads what is in the cookie and then changes the style sheet accordingly. I am a bit unsure of how to go about generating cookies with php and how to implement that does anyone have any ideas? any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your Problem, what you have tried to solve, and where specific you have problems.

Comment: [What research have you done?](http://davidwalsh.name/php-cookies)

Comment: Have you read http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php and it's unclear to you? Or do you have a specific problem, like you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "styelsheet";
$cookie_value = "styelsheet2.css";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
// 86400 = 1 day
?>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    $stylesheet = "default.css";
} else {
    $stylesheet =  $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tariq Hussain

Bad approach to direct assign file name
`$stylesheet = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];`

---

A fine approach can be :

```
<?php
    $stylesheet = 'default.css';
    if(file_exists(PATH_TO_STYLESHEET_FILES. $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]))
    $stylesheet = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
?>
```

`$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]` can be modified to defeat the system and fall into other security issues..

Further reading
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-totally-secure-cookies